# error TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'Response'

Tags: json, firebase, angular, last.fm, typescript1.8

I followed a piece of code building and app that collect data from last.fm using angular2, typescript and firebase.

the source code can be found here: https://github.com/vtts/mytunes

***QUESTION how can I cast the results from the json calls?***

### Source code on github

https://github.com/vtts/mytunes/blob/master/app/music/services/music.srv.ts

### I receive the following errors:

```
app/music/services/music.service.ts(29,39): error TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'Response'. 
app/music/services/music.service.ts(51,36): error TS2339: Property 'album' does not exist on type 'Response'.
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "mytunes",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "firebase": "^2.4.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^0.7.12"
  }
}
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "js"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

### Last.fm REST API

I am using the following REST APIs:

- http://www.last.fm/api/show/album.search
- http://www.last.fm/api/scrobbling

Comment: Looks like the problem is in this line https://github.com/vtts/mytunes/blob/943702542e9249b57ec9ee7348375d863af21bb3/app/music/services/music.srv.ts#L29
Try printing `res` to console and check whether it actually has  a `results` key.

Comment: dear @GünterZöchbauer, I can't even run the application because the compilation fails

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of reusing the variable `res` which is typed as `Response`

```
res = res.json();
```

create a new one

```
let result = res.json();
```

and then use `result` for the following lines instead of `res`

Comment: Dear @GünterZöchbauer your proposal is already in place in the the line 29 and the same issue occurs too.

Comment: Then delete line 27 and put 29 on its place.

Comment: obviously, you are right, I was debugging for too long this piece of code. Many Thanks